# Element 'all' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to allow the following XML pattern:

```
<Locales>
    <Locale Language="FR">
        <Name>La Jetée</Name>
    </Locale>
    <Locale Language="EN">
        <Name>The Jetty</Name>
    </Locale>
</Locales>
```

Here is the XSD I currently have, but it is giving an error about the attributes. When I remove the attributes it validates

```
<xs:element name="Locales" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Locale" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Language" use="optional"/>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The error I get is

> Element 'all' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your XSD is fine except that you have to move `xs:all` *before* `xs:attribute`; it may not appear *after* `xs:attribute`, thus the error.**

Here is your XSD fragment with the above change applied:

```
  <xs:element name="Locales">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Locale" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:attribute name="Language" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

It will successfully validate your XML.  Note that it also removes `minOccurs="0"` because occurrence constraints may not appear on top-level elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be able to use a tool such as http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html to infer the xsd structure that's required.

For the above case, something like the following should work:

```
<xs:element name="Locales">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Locale" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Language" use="optional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Tools that infer an XSD from XML are inherently limited.  In even this small example, we can see numerous assumptions that differ from your original XSD.  Better to attack such small errors head-on and resolve the issue directly; save the XSD inference tools for use as a starting point for massive XML instances.